# class inheritance in javascript/angular

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, inheritance

I am working on my hello world project. I have two pages let's call them "configuration" and "add configuration" *.html. Each one has its own controller like this:

```
angular.module('MissionControlApp').controller('ConfigController', ConfigController);

angular.module('MissionControlApp').controller('AddConfigController', AddConfigController);
```

Now, each controller has some properties that very much overlap:

```
function ConfigController($routeParams, ConfigFactory, $window){
    var vm = this;
    vm.status;
    vm.projectId = $routeParams.projectId;
    vm.selectedProject;
    vm.configurations;
    vm.selectedConfig;
    vm.selectedRecords;
    vm.filteredConfig;
    vm.newFile;
    vm.fileWarningMsg = '';

vm.addFile = function(){
        var filePath = vm.newFile;
        var encodedUri = encodeURIComponent(filePath);
        vm.fileWarningMsg='';

        ConfigFactory
            .getByEncodedUri(encodedUri).then(function(response){
                var configFound = response.data;
                var configNames = '';
                var configMatched = false;
                if(response.status === 200 && configFound.length > 0){
                    //find an exact match from text search result
                    for(var i = 0; i < configFound.length; i++) {
                        var config = configFound[i];
                        for(var j=0; j<config.files.length; j++){
                            var file = config.files[j];
                            if(file.centralPath.toLowerCase() === filePath.toLowerCase()){
                                configMatched = true;
                                configNames += ' [' + config.name + '] ';
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(configMatched){
                    vm.fileWarningMsg = 'Warning! File already exists in other configurations.\n' + configNames;
                } else if(filePath.length > 0 && filePath.includes('.rvt')){
                    var file1 = { centralPath: filePath };
                    vm.selectedConfig.files.push(file1);
                    vm.newFile = '';
                } else{
                    vm.fileWarningMsg = 'Warning! Please enter a valid file.';
                }

            }, function(error){
                vm.status = 'Unable to get configuration data: ' + error.message;
            });

    };
```

My `AddConfigController` also wants to have the same functionality for `addFile()` so I just copy pasted the same code, but coming from C# i am sure i can do some class inheritance here, and just inherit from `ConfigController` and extend...right?

If this is super noob question. then apologies. js is a bit of a mystery to me.

```
function AddConfigController($routeParams, ConfigFactory, $window){
    var vm = this;
    vm.status;
    vm.projectId = $routeParams.projectId;
    vm.selectedProject = {};
    vm.newConfig = {};
    vm.newFile;
    vm.fileWarningMsg = '';

vm.addFile = function(){
        var filePath = vm.newFile;
        var encodedUri = encodeURIComponent(filePath);
        vm.fileWarningMsg='';

        ConfigFactory
            .getByEncodedUri(encodedUri).then(function(response){
                var configFound = response.data;
                var configNames = '';
                var configMatched = false;
                if(response.status === 200 && configFound.length > 0){
                    //find an exact match from text search result
                    for(var i = 0; i < configFound.length; i++) {
                        var config = configFound[i];
                        for(var j=0; j<config.files.length; j++){
                            var file = config.files[j];
                            if(file.centralPath.toLowerCase() === filePath.toLowerCase()){
                                configMatched = true;
                                configNames += ' [' + config.name + '] ';
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(configMatched){
                    vm.fileWarningMsg = 'Warning! File already exists in other configurations.\n' + configNames;
                } else if(filePath.length > 0 && filePath.includes('.rvt')){
                    var file1 = { centralPath: filePath };
                    vm.selectedConfig.files.push(file1);
                    vm.newFile = '';
                } else{
                    vm.fileWarningMsg = 'Warning! Please enter a valid file.';
                }

            }, function(error){
                vm.status = 'Unable to get configuration data: ' + error.message;
            });

    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked about inheritance and you appear to be using ECMAScript 5, let me suggest taking a look at [`Object.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create).  Specifically, the [classical inheritance example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create#Classical_inheritance_with_Object.create%28%29).

That said, in AngularJS, a better solution would be to create a [Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) that manages files or configurations and put the `addFile` function in there.  That way, both controllers could inject the service and call the same function when it is time to add a file.  Likewise, other services and controllers that may need access to this functionality could inject it as well.